# Add github javascript library

Tags: javascript, html, github, q

I want to add a javascript library from github in my webpage, in order to merge it with my code.. How can I do that? 
I want to add this library: https://github.com/kriskowal/q

I'm trying to run the code, but it give me an Uncaught ReferenceError: Q is not defined.
What should I do?

Comment: Add a src tag that points to [the link of the version you want as seen here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/q.js) `<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/q.js/2.0.3/q.js'></script>`

Comment: I don't think there is the last version there, is there a way to add it?

Comment: They tell you the various ways it can be loaded in the docs. https://github.com/kriskowal/q#getting-started

Comment: Here's the latest version as a CDN. It's on the Q gitub repo page. Follow @pmkro's advice above and use the link in my comment. https://cdnjs.com/libraries/q.js

Comment: I've tried it but I get another error Uncaught TypeError: Q.async is not a function. I've tried to copy the q.js file in github and paste it into my website, then added the src tag that point to the link of the the q.js file in my website and it's working. But I think it should be better if it could point to the q.js in the github repo

Answer (score 0):

As many have stated in comments, you can simply create a script tag such as the following:

`<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/kriskowal/q/8545bd6f/q.js"></script>`

The above is best for production.  You can use the following for dev:

`<script src="https://rawgit.com/kriskowal/q/master/q.js"></script>`

As you can see I am just using rawgit.  Check it out here:
https://rawgit.com/